# How to make a Xamarin application continue running even when the phone is turned off or the application is closed?

Tags: c#, xamarin, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to know if anyone knows how to make a Xamarin application continue running even when the phone is restarted or turned off, or when the application is closed. I'm not sure if there is a native way that can work on both Android and iOS. My project has the following: In the main project (the shared one), I have a CRUD class that performs the following:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using ToDo.App.Models;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace ToDo.App.Services
{
    public class SchedulerTaskService
    {
        ToDoItem _Item;
        Android.Content.Context _context;
        public SchedulerTaskService()
        {
            
        }
        public SchedulerTaskService(ToDoItem Item, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            _Item = Item;
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<ToDoItem> ScheduleTask()
        {
            var lstDeserializeListOfWeek = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DayOfWeekModel>>(_Item.ObjDaysToRepeat);
            List<DayOfWeek> targetDays = await GetDaysFromModel(lstDeserializeListOfWeek);

            // Define the target days of the week
            //List<DayOfWeek> targetDays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DayOfWeek>>(_Item.ObjDaysToRepeat);
            List<System.Timers.Timer> lstTimers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Schedule timer for each target day of the week
                foreach (DayOfWeek targetDay in targetDays)
                {
                    // Get the next target day
                    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                    int daysUntilNextTargetDay = ((int)targetDay - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
                    DateTime nextTargetDay = today.AddDays(daysUntilNextTargetDay);

                    // Set the start time for the timer
                    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(_Item.Hour.Hours, _Item.Hour.Minutes, _Item.Hour.Seconds);
                    DateTime startDateTime = nextTargetDay + startTime;

                    // Calculate the initial delay until the first timer elapses
                    TimeSpan initialDelay = startDateTime - DateTime.Now;

                    // Set timer properties

                    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds > 0 ? initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds : initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds * -1);
                    //var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

                    if (_Item.WithInterval != 0)
                    {
                        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(_Item.WithInterval).TotalMilliseconds;
                    }

                    //timer.AutoReset = true;

                    // Start the timer
                    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
                    timer.Start();

                    lstTimers.Add(timer);

                }

            });

            _Item.ObjTimer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstTimers.ToList());
            int result = await App.Context.InsertItemAsync(_Item);
            if (result == 1)
                return _Item;
            else
                CancelTask(lstTimers);

            return null;

        }

        public async Task<ToDoItem> EditScheduleAsync()
        {
            var lstDeserializeListOfWeek = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DayOfWeekModel>>(_Item.ObjDaysToRepeat);
            List<DayOfWeek> targetDays = await GetDaysFromModel(lstDeserializeListOfWeek);

            // Define the target days of the week
            
            List<System.Timers.Timer> lstTimers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();

            CancelTask(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<System.Timers.Timer>>(_Item.ObjTimer));

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                // Schedule timer for each target day of the week
                foreach (DayOfWeek targetDay in targetDays)
                {
                    // Get the next target day
                    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                    int daysUntilNextTargetDay = ((int)targetDay - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
                    DateTime nextTargetDay = today.AddDays(daysUntilNextTargetDay);

                    // Set the start time for the timer
                    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(_Item.Hour.Hours, _Item.Hour.Minutes, _Item.Hour.Seconds);
                    DateTime startDateTime = nextTargetDay + startTime;

                    // Calculate the initial delay until the first timer elapses
                    TimeSpan initialDelay = startDateTime - DateTime.Now;

                    // Set timer properties

                    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds > 0 ? initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds : initialDelay.TotalMilliseconds * -1);
                    //var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

                    if (_Item.WithInterval != 0)
                    {
                        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(_Item.WithInterval).TotalMilliseconds;
                    }

                    //timer.AutoReset = true;

                    // Start the timer
                    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
                    timer.Start();

                    lstTimers.Add(timer);

                }

            });

            _Item.ObjTimer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstTimers.ToList());
            _Item.CreateTime = DateTime.Now;
            int result = await App.Context.EditItemAsync(_Item);
            if (result == 1)
                return _Item;
            else
                CancelTask(lstTimers);

            return null;

        }

        private async void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                #region TaskHere

                // Implement your task here
                var locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();

                // Grab the first locale
                var locale = locales.FirstOrDefault();

                var settings = new SpeechOptions()
                {
                    Volume = 1.0f,
                    Pitch = 0.70f,
                    Locale = locale
                };


                await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(_Item.Description, settings);
                await Task.Delay(2000);

                await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(_Item.Description, settings);
                await Task.Delay(2000);

                await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(_Item.Description, settings);

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            // Task to run every 5 hours on each target day of the week

            

        }

        public async void CancelTask(List<System.Timers.Timer> InLstTimers)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in InLstTimers)
                {
                    item.Enabled = false;
                    item.Dispose();
                    item.Stop();
                   
                }
            });
        }

        private async Task<List<DayOfWeek>> GetDaysFromModel(List<DayOfWeekModel> ModelWeek)
        {
            List<System.DayOfWeek> lstselectedDays = new List<System.DayOfWeek>();
            #region LllenadoListaDayOfWeek

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //listViewDaysOfWeek.ItemsSource
                foreach (DayOfWeekModel item in ModelWeek)
                {
                    if (item.IsChecked)
                    {
                        switch (item.DayOfWeek)
                        {
                            case "Monday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Monday);
                                break;
                            case "Tuesday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Tuesday);
                                break;
                            case "Wednesday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
                                break;
                            case "Thursday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Thursday);
                                break;
                            case "Friday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Friday);
                                break;
                            case "Saturday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Saturday);
                                break;
                            case "Sunday":
                                lstselectedDays.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }

            });

            #endregion
            return lstselectedDays;

        }
```

And I call it when someone wants to add or edit a new task from a XAML view. This is the C# code for that XAML view (also located in the shared project):

```
using Android.App;
using Android.App.Job;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ToDo.App.Models;
using ToDo.App.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.AppCompat;
using Android.App.AppSearch;
using Android;
using Java.Sql;
using System.Threading;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using static Android.Content.ClipData;
using static Android.OS.Build;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Widget;
using ToDo.App.Strategy;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
using Android.Text.Format;
using System.ComponentModel;
//using static Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard;
//using static Android.Util.EventLogTags;

//using Java.Lang;

namespace ToDo.App.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AddPage : ContentPage
    {
        //JobScheduler jobScheduler;
        //ServiceDownloadJob service;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
        ToDoItem result = null;
        int EditItemId = 0;
        bool isEdit = false;
        bool isAddInterval = false;

        List<DayOfWeekModel> daysOfWeekList = null;

        public AddPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillcboDayOfWeek();
        }

        public AddPage(ToDoItem item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillFields(item);
        }

        private async void BtnGuardar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                var selectedDays = daysOfWeekList.Where(d => d.IsChecked).ToList();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(descripcion.Text) || selectedDays.Count() <= 0)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "No puedes dejar campos vacíos.\n\n", "Aceptar");
                    return;
                }

                var existName = await App.Context.FindItemByNameAsync(nombre.Text);
                if (existName != null && !isEdit)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "No puedes tener más de una tarea con el mismo nombre.\n\n" + " Porfavor elige otro nombre para tu tarea", "Aceptar");
                    return;
                }


                //ValidationForm(selectedDays);

                var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                ToDoItem inItem = new ToDoItem();

                if(isEdit)
                    inItem = await App.Context.FindItemAsync(EditItemId);

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    inItem.WithInterval = 0;
                    inItem.Hour = TimePicker.Time;
                    inItem.Name = nombre.Text;
                    inItem.Description = descripcion.Text;

                    // iterar sobre la lista de modelos de días de la semana
                    // get list of selected days
                    inItem.ObjDaysToRepeat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedDays);

                    if (isAddInterval && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInterval.Text))
                    {
                        inItem.WithInterval = Convert.ToInt32(txtInterval.Text);
                        inItem.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt32(txtInterval.Text));
                    }
                });

                SchedulerTaskService schedulTaskAsync = new SchedulerTaskService(inItem, context);

                if (isEdit)
                {
                    result = await schedulTaskAsync.EditScheduleAsync();
                    isEdit = false;
                    EditItemId = 0;
                }
                else
                    result = await schedulTaskAsync.ScheduleTask();
                

                if (result != null)
                {
                    //await Task.Delay((int)SleepProccess);
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Se programó correctamente la alarma", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();

                }
                else
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "No se pudo guardar la tarea", "Aceptar");
                

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    var findItem = await App.Context.FindItemAsync(result.Id);
                    var Deleteresult = await App.Context.DeleteItemAsync(result);
                    List<System.Timers.Timer> CancelDaysAlarm= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<System.Timers.Timer>>(findItem.ObjTimer);

                    if (Deleteresult == 1)
                    {
                        SchedulerTaskService taskScheduler = new SchedulerTaskService();
                        taskScheduler.CancelTask(CancelDaysAlarm);
                    }
                }

                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");
            }
        }

        private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // handle checkbox checked event
            var checkbox = sender as Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox;
            var checkedState = checkbox.IsChecked;
            var dayOfWeek = checkbox.BindingContext as DayOfWeekModel;

            // update the IsChecked property in the DayOfWeekModel object
            dayOfWeek.IsChecked = checkedState;
        }

        private void chkIntervalo_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbIntervalo.IsVisible = e.Value;
            txtInterval.IsVisible = e.Value;

            if (txtInterval.IsVisible)
                isAddInterval = true;
            else
                isAddInterval = false;

        }

        private void FillcboDayOfWeek()
        {

            daysOfWeekList = new List<DayOfWeekModel>
            {
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Monday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Tuesday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Wednesday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Thursday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Friday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Saturday" },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Sunday" }
            };

            // set the listview's itemssource to the list of days of the week
            listViewDaysOfWeek.ItemsSource = daysOfWeekList;
        }

        private List<DayOfWeekModel> GetDaysLisDayOfWeekModel()
        {
            daysOfWeekList = new List<DayOfWeekModel>
            {
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Monday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Tuesday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Wednesday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Thursday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Friday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Saturday", IsChecked = false },
                new DayOfWeekModel { DayOfWeek = "Sunday", IsChecked = false }
            };

            return daysOfWeekList;
        }

        private async void FillFields(ToDoItem item)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    #region DataEdit
                    TimePicker.Time = item.Hour;
                    nombre.Text = item.Name;
                    descripcion.Text = item.Description;
                    isEdit = true;
                    EditItemId = item.Id;

                    if (item.WithInterval != 0)
                    {
                        txtInterval.Text = item.WithInterval.ToString();
                        chkIntervalo.IsChecked = true;
                    }

                    List<DayOfWeekModel> LstCheckedDaysOfWeek = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DayOfWeekModel>>(item.ObjDaysToRepeat).ToList();
                    List<DayOfWeekModel> DaysOfWeek = GetDaysLisDayOfWeekModel().ToList();

                    var lstNotIn = (from c in DaysOfWeek
                                    where !(from o in LstCheckedDaysOfWeek
                                            select o.DayOfWeek)
                                          .Contains(c.DayOfWeek)
                                    select c).ToList();

                    daysOfWeekList = LstCheckedDaysOfWeek.Union(lstNotIn).ToList();

                    listViewDaysOfWeek.ItemsSource = daysOfWeekList;

                    #endregion
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");
            }

        }

        private async void ValidationForm(List<DayOfWeekModel> CheckedDays)
        {
            //List<DayOfWeekModel>
            //var CheckedDays = daysOfWeekList.Where(d => d.IsChecked).ToList();
           
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(descripcion.Text) || CheckedDays.Count() <= 0)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No puedes dejar campos vacíos.\n\n", "Aceptar");
                return;
            }

            var existName = await App.Context.FindItemByNameAsync(nombre.Text);
            if (existName != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No puedes tener más de una tarea con el mismo nombre.\n\n" + " Porfavor elige otro nombre para tu tarea", "Aceptar");
                return;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The code works perfectly, but when the application is closed or the phone is restarted, the scheduled tasks no longer work. I hope you can help me.

I have tried various methods like JobScheduler and some other ways with background services, but it seems that they only work for Android and don't work in the shared project section.

Comment: You need a startup service : https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/mobile/9781784398576/6/ch06lvl1sec68/starting-services-automatically

Comment: For IOS, if your app is put into background, Apple has strict limit to allow apps running in the background.  You can check this article about [Backgrounding in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/).